# What width of image required to fulfill width of android screen

Tags: android, android-layout

On  an android xml file or graphical layout

I want to create an imageview that hold an image.

My question here is what the width of the image in pixels required to  fulfill the Android Mobile width.

Comment: You should read the design guidelines and developer training here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html . There is no single size you can use in pixels, there are too many different devices. However if you set layout_width="fill_parent" and layout_height="fill_parent" on the image view it will take up the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since different Android devices have different screen sizes, you won't be able to set an absolute width to fill the screen. You can use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` as the width for the ImageView and it will resize itself to fit the parent view it's added to.

Comment: Agree with this. Android development is different than developing for PCs. You shouldn't think in terms of pixel sizes because you don't know how big the phone is.

Answer (score 1):

just write that in xml under ImageView tag

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

thats it

Answer (score 1):

The device width of each android device differs. If you would like to fulfill the image on a device, then it might be streched or truncated on four sides based on the Image width. It would be a nice idea make hte image center, so it looks on all the devices or you might need different sizes of the same image depends on the device widht and height